# How to align with the title of the Toolbar?

Tags: android

I'm trying to align a row with an icon and a text field with the navigation button and title of the toolbar, respectively.

According to the design specification, the title is 72dp away from the left edge:

[image]

If I use 72dp, like below, I don't get an alignment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="56dp"
               android:layout_height="56dp"
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:id="@+id/icon"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
</merge>
```

[image]

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE** Customised the toolbar as per @Mike's advice:

[image]

[image]

Comment: your adding padding to your ImageView which is throwing off the alignment as well... enable Draw layout bounds in your Developer Settings too, which will help you see that your imageView bounds are getting moved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to mention is that the title on the screenshot you pasted is not at 72dp from left but it rather looks like 56dp.

Basically the problem is that Google writes something in their documentation but when it comes to implement things they do it differently.

[Here](https://medium.com/@lucasurbas/making-android-toolbar-responsive-2627d4e07129#.d1un0y8zn) is a really great post from [Lucas Urbas](https://medium.com/@lucasurbas) explaining in detail all the Toolbar misunderstandings on Android.

Comment: Do you know why this might be the case if the spec states 72dp? The emulator is using API 22 on a Nexus 4.

Comment: It's basically because Google writes something in it's documentation and they do something else when it comes to implement things :). I'll edit my answer with a great post you should consider reading to clarify everything.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying out the solution, but do you know where those themes `@style/Toolbar.AppCompat.Responsive` and `@style/Toolbar.Popup.AppCompat` comes from?

Comment: He is building those as custom styles. Please look at the "Action Mode" section at the end. You can always build your own styles.

Comment: I've made the changes as per suggestions, but the alignment turns out to be slightly off. Please see update.

Comment: The alignment seems to be correct but EditTexts have a default padding(of 8dp I think?) that's why it looks off...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92911/discussion-between-mike-and-kar).

Comment: I think this fix only works if the elements on the left and right of the menu are icons rather than texts. If my menu was 'Done', a right padding of 4dp won't be enough, because text menu items are padded by just 4dp - I think? So it'll be 8dp off?